# tcolorbox package: padding around vertical line in side-by side vertically split box

Tags: spacing, tcolorbox, padding

I have defined a tcolorbox with two parts "side by side". These parts are separated by a vertical dashed line generated by the  `\tcblower` command.
I'd like to reduce the padding between the text (or image) in each box and the box frame. I was able to control "external" padding with the `boxsep`, `left` and `right` parameters, but I cannot seem to be able to reduce the padding around the vertical dashed line.
I tried with `middle`, `leftlower`, `rightlower` and so on, but to no avail. Whatever value I set the padding seems to stay the same.

Here's a mwe

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\tcbset{enhanced,colframe=black!35!white,beforeafter skip=0pt,boxsep=0mm,
left = 1mm, right=1mm, leftlower=1mm, rightlower=1mm, 
boxrule=0.25mm}

\newtcolorbox{B11}[2]{after skip=2pt,arc=2mm,rounded corners,
halign=justify,sidebyside,sidebyside align = top seam,
righthand width = #2\linewidth,attach boxed title to top
left={xshift=-2mm,yshift=-2mm},fonttitle=\bfseries,colback=white,
title=#1,coltitle=white,boxed title
style={colback=black!40,boxrule=0.2mm}}

\begin{document}

\begin{B11}{some title}{0.3}
\lipsum[1]
\tcblower
\lipsum[2]
\end{B11}
\end{document}
```

Thanks a lot for your insight.
Francesco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need `sidebyide gap=<length>`. You can use it either in the definition of the `\newtcolorbox` or as a setting in `\tcbset`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\tcbset{enhanced,colframe=black!35!white,beforeafter skip=0pt,boxsep=0mm,
    left = 1mm, right=1mm, leftlower=1mm, rightlower=1mm, 
    boxrule=0.25mm}

\newtcolorbox{B11}[2]{after skip=2pt,arc=2mm,rounded corners,
    halign=justify,sidebyside,sidebyside align = top seam,
    righthand width = #2\linewidth,attach boxed title to top
    left={xshift=-2mm,yshift=-2mm},fonttitle=\bfseries,colback=white,
    title=#1,coltitle=white,boxed title
    style={colback=black!40,boxrule=0.2mm},sidebyside gap=10pt}%<<<<<<<< see here

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{B11}{some title}{0.3}
        \lipsum[1]
        \tcblower
        \lipsum[2]
    \end{B11}
\end{document}
```